# Optimization and loadbalancing of microservice based backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, microservices, backend, load-balancing

I have a client which has a pretty popular ticket selling service, to the point that the microservice based backend is struggling to keep up, I need to come up with a solution to optimize and loadbalance the system. The infrastructure works through a series of interconnected microservices.

When a user enter the sales channels (mobile or web app), the request is directed to an AWS API Gateway which is in charge of orchestrating the communication towards the microservice in charge of obtaining the requested resources.

These resources are provided from a third party API

- This third party has physical servers in each venue in charge of synchronizing the information between the POS systems and the digital sales channels.
- We have a REDIS instance in charge of caching these requests that we make to the third party API, we cache each endpoint with a TTL relative to the frequency of updating the information.

Here is some background info:

- We get traffic mostly from 2 major countries
- On a normal day, about 100 thousands users will use the service, with an 70%/30% traffic relation in between the two countries
- On important days, each country has different opening hours (Country A starts sales at 10 am UTC, but country B starts at 5 pm UTC), on these days the traffic increases some n times
- We have a main MiddleWare through which all requests made by clients are processed.
- We have a REDIS cache database that stores GETs with different TTLs for each endpoint.
- We have a MiddleWare that decides to make the request to the cache or to the third party's API, as the case may be.

And these are the complaints I have gotten that need to be deal with:

- When a country receives a high amount of requests, the country with the least traffic gets negatively affected, the clients do not respond, or respond partially because the computation layer's limit was exceeded and so the users have a bad experience
- Every time the above happens, the computation layer must be manually increased from the infrastructure.
- Each request has different response times, stadiums respond in +/- 40 seconds and movie theaters in 3 seconds. These requests enter a queue and are answered in order of arrival.
- The error handling is not clear. The errors are mixed up and you can't tell from which country the errors are coming from and how many errors there are
- The responses from the third party API are not cached correctly in the cache layer since errors are stored for the time of the TTL

I was thinking of a couple of thinks that I could suggest:

- Adding in instrumentation of the requests by using AWS X-Ray
- Adding in a separate table for errors in the redis cache layer (old data has to be better than no data for the end user)
- Adding in AWS elastic load balancing for the main middleware

But I'm not sure how realistic would be to implement these 3 things, I'm also not sure if they would even solve the problem, I personally don't really have experience with optimizing this type of backed. I would appreciate any suggestions, recommendations, links, documentation, etc. I'm really desperate for a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

few thoughts:

- When a country receives a high amount of requests, the country with the least traffic gets negatively affected, the clients do not respond, or respond partially because the computation layer's limit was exceeded and so the users have a bad experience

A common approach in aws is to regionalize stack - assuming you are using cdk/cloud formation creating regionalized stack should be a straightforward task.

But it is a question if this will solve the problem. Your system suffers from availability issues, regionalization will isolate this problem down to regions. So we should be able to do better (see below)

- Every time the above happens, the computation layer must be manually increased from the infrastructure.

AWS has an option to automatically scale up and down based on traffic patterns. This is a neat feature, given you set limits to make sure you are not overcharged.

- Each request has different response times, stadiums respond in +/- 40 seconds and movie theaters in 3 seconds. These requests enter a queue and are answered in order of arrival.

It seems that the large variance is because you have to contact the servers at venues. I recommend to decouple that activity. Basically calls to venues should be done async; there are several ways you could do that - queues and customer push/pull are the approaches (please, comment if more details are needed. but this is quite standard problem - lots of data in the internet)

- The error handling is not clear. The errors are mixed up and you can't tell from which country the errors are coming from and how many errors there are

That's a code fix, when you do send data to cloudwatch (do you?). You could put country as a context to all request, via filter or something. And when error is logged that context is logged as well. You probably need venue id even more than country, as you can conclude country from venue id.

- The responses from the third party API are not cached correctly in the cache layer since errors are stored for the time of the TTL

Don't store errors + add a circuit breaker pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @AndrewR! I had some questions for you if that's ok:
1. Would the multi region app be servicing one country per region strictly? Or would the second region work as a fail over?
2. How can I configure the multi region app to send any errors to the same cloudwatch?
3. Can you go a bit into detail in regards to the costumer queue or costumer push/pull?

Comment: Teams tend to use region per country to minimize latency (for example, google aws latency between regions). If a region is down, another region takes over for availability. All errors/logs should stay within region - inter region calls are slow and are availability risks. If you want to search - you could send all regional logs into one s3 bucket and search there (using Athena for example). At the end of the day - I would think how much of a big deal is the latency - I would keep two regions for availability and simplicity.

Comment: Using a queue is a common pattern to decouple a request coming from a customer with a job executed in the backend. This is important when the job takes long time. In that case, the request starts a job by putting all needed data in a queue; and then immediately returns to customer "work in progress". Then the customer waits for job to be done. The customer will either pull - e.g. every second; or (better) the server will try to push via a web socket of other long lived connection - this will provide a better customer experience.